# Inner join in combination with sum and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some strange issue with the SQL statement below. The result groups by user IDs and some of them turn out right but for one of them (user ID = 1) the "initial_average" is multiplied by 3. I really have no idea why.. Is there something wrong with the structure of the statement? If it is not clear, the aim is to sum the field "initial_avg" in the "tasks" table and have it broken out by user. Some help with this is much appreciated. I am using MySQL.

```
SELECT sum(initial_avg) AS initial_average
     , sum(initial_std) AS initial_standard_dev
     , tasks.user
     , hourly_rate 
FROM tasks 
INNER JOIN user_project 
   ON tasks.user=user_project.user 
  AND tasks.project=59 
  AND tasks.user=1 
GROUP BY tasks.user
```

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data  sample

Comment: I just solved it by adding another "and" clause (AND user_project.project=59 )

Comment: probably should group by hourly_rate.  and since you're using an inner join the `and tasks.project=-59 and tasks.user=1` should really be in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by adding another "and" clause (AND user_project.project=59 )

Answer (score 0):

Optimize your query (Try it):

```
SELECT SUM(initial_avg) AS initial_average, SUM(initial_std) AS initial_standard_dev, tasks.user, hourly_rate FROM tasks INNER JOIN user_project ON tasks.user = user_project.user AND tasks.project = User_project.project WHERE tasks.project = 59 AND tasks.user = 1 GROUP BY tasks.user, hourly_rate
```